# Finding Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

So, i have ${f(t)}={t}e^{-2t}\cos{(5t)}$.
How to find Laplace transform? Which properties should we use? If I am not mistaken, $f(t)$ - original, $\mathcal{L}(f(t))$ - image.
Correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: Laplace transform of $f(t)$ is an integration by parts.

Comment: Are you allowed to cite the Laplace transform of $e^{-2t}\cos(5t)$? You can do this problem directly from the definition but which properties are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood. So, we have ${t}e^{-2t}\cos{5t} = {t}f(t)$.

From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can use property: Frequency-domain general derivative.

$\mathcal{L}({t}f(t)) = -F'(s)$